# when query at JPA - JPQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

My system required to add filters,and I'm wonder if there any query that like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p
when byDate is not null then (where p.createAt BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
when byType is not null then (where p.type = :type)
```

I knew that the query is not valid, but I want at **one query** to get the data wherever the request has (no filter or all filters or some of filters).

My goal is to create one query to achieve all cases.

Comment: sorry no, according to the  documentation https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *usually* not a good idea to write a big SQL query when you can tell in advance the actual query you want to run.

If you want to run a different query based on conditions you know before running the query, there are different approaches in JPA or Spring that you can use

## Spring

You can define the different queries using [Spring Data query methods](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-data-jpa-query-creation-from-method-names.html)?

```
public class PostRepository implements JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findByCreatedAtBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
    List<Post> findByTypeIs(String type);
}
```

And then somewhere in the code, you can:

```
List<Post> results = null;
if (byDate != null) {
   results = repository.findByCreatedAtBetween(startDate, endDate);
} else if (byType != null) {
   results = repository.findByTypeIs(type);
} else {
   results = repository.findAll();
}
```

### Criteria

With [criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria) you can create a dynamic query at runtime and execute it:

```
public class PostRepository implements PostRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Post> findPosts(Filter filter) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(Post.class);
        Root<User> user = query.from(Post.class);

        if ((filter.getByDate() != null)) {
          // byDate is not null
          ParameterExpression<Date> startDate = builder.parameter( Date.class );
          ParameterExpression<Date> endDate = builder.parameter( Date.class );
          query.where(builder.between( b.get( "createdAt" ), startDate, endDate));
          return em.createQuery(query)
                   .setParameter(startDate, ...)
                   .setParameter(endDate, ...)
                   .getResultList();
        }
        
        if (filter.getByType() != null) {
          ParameterExpression<Date> typeParam = builder.parameter( Date.class );

          query.where(builder.and(root.get("type"), typeParam));
          return em.createQuery(query)
                   .setParameter(typeParam, ...)
                   .getResultList();

        }

        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
            .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Assuming that your entity has the fields `type` and `createdAt`.
This approach works well if you don't know in advance what's your query looks like. For example, when you don't know how many conditions you will have to add to it.

But, if I know already which query I want to run, then I prefer to use HQL/JPQL.

## HQL

If your queries don't change and you already know what they look like,
I find it easier to define them with [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql):

```
public class PostRepository implements PostRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Post> findPosts(Filter filter) {
       if (filter.getByDate() != null) {
          return em.createQuery("from Post p where p.createdAt between :startDate and :endDate", Post.class)
                    .setParameter("startDate", ...)
                    .setParameter("endDate", ...)
                    .getResultList();
       }
       if (filter.getByType() != null) {
          return em.createQuery("from Post p where p.type =:type", Post.class)
                    .setParameter("type", ...)
                    .getResultList();
       }
       return em.createQuery("from Post", Post.class)
                    .getResultList();       
    }
}
```

You can refactor the code to make it more elegant, but it should give you an idea. Note that if you need to reuse the same queries in different services, it might be helpful to define them using the annotation `@NamedQuery`.

## Filters

In Hibernate (not JPA) you can also [define filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter). They are SQL filter conditions that one can apply at runtime:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = Post.BY_DATE, defaultCondition = "createdAt between :startDate and :endDate", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "startDate", type = "date"), @ParamDef(name = "startDate", type = "date") })
@FilterDef(name = Post.BY_TYPE, defaultCondition = "type = :type", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "startDate", type = "date"))
@Filter(name = Post.BY_DATE)
@Filter(name = Post.BY_TYPE)
class Post {
   static final String BY_DATE = "Post.byDateFilter";
   static final String BY_TYPE = "Post.byFilter"

   private String type;
   private Date createdAt;
   ...
}
```

Then:

```
public class PostRepository implements PostRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Post> findPosts(Filter filter) {
       enableFilters(em);
       return em.createQuery("from Post", Post.class).getResultList();
    }

    private void enableFilters(Filter filter, EntityManager em) {
       if (filter.getByDate() != null) {
          em.unwrap(Session.class)
            .enableFilter( Post.BY_DATE )
            .setParameter("startDate", ...)
            .setParameter("endDate", ...);
       } else if (filter.getByType() != null) {
          em.unwrap(Session.class)
            .enableFilter( Post.BY_TYPE )
            .setParameter("type", ...);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @Davide D'Alto, But is not worked for me :( & another Q: what if have more than 2 filters, should I cover all cases!

Comment: Can you explain how it failed? Is it a specific use case? Yes, you should cover all cases. But you cover them anyway with the when-then clause. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I do something like this, but I got only the  p.is_anonymous = 0 wherever the byAnony is 0 or 1 

SELECT *
FROM topics p
WHERE
    (:byAnony is null or (p.is_anonymous = 0))
  and
    (:byAnony is not null or (:byUsername is null and p.user_id = 2))

Comment: This is different than what you've asked in the question. Can you write it as a when-then clause? Isn't this the same as ```WHERE (byAnony not in (0, 1) or p.is_anonymous = 0)```

Comment: I think the answer is correct, but if it's too much trouble you can always run the `when-then` query as a native SQL query.

Comment: Really thanks @Davide D'Alto, So do you think this approach is really complext when we have a list of filters? - and do u this approach will work better for me https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#dynamic-query ?

Comment: Ah, I see now. I thought `byDate` was a column. Yes, if you know in advance which query you have to run there's no reason to have a mega SQL (IMHO). You can create them dynamically each time (like in the article). But you could also define them in advance using `@NamedQuery` or maybe [you can activate a predefined filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter).

Comment: I will update my answer later

Comment: Thanks @Davide D'Alto , I'm waiting for u updated answer.

Comment: I've just realized that you don't need a CustomRepository and you could do this just using Spring. I've added it in the answer. Good Luck

Comment: By using Spring I have to cover all cases! that is what I don't like, but In general thanks for the help. @Davide D'Alto